# Odd behavior in Firefox Developer Edition, the "inspect Element" context menu option

Tags: firefox, web-inspector

I'm super stoked about the Firefox Developer Edition! I am using it now and like it. But there is a behavior in the contextual menu that's really bugging me.

In "stable" Firefox, when I right click on an item and hit the "Inspect element" option, the inspector comes up and the DOM tree is open to the item that the cursor was over.

In Developer Edition (the Aurora track) when I do the above action it only opens the DOM tree to "body". Is this happening to anyone else? And is there an option that I have missed that will fix this?

Edit 11/13/2014 9:01 am

I had a bit of :facepalm: moment when I realized I could hit the icon at the far left of the tool bar in the inspector, which turns on "Select by clicking". Which helps, but it still doesn't quite address my issue/question about using the *super handy* right click "Inspect Element" issue.

Comment: I've found that problem in both release and dev-edition, but only on my work PC. Dev edition worked initially, but broke within an hour. From that, I assume it's an environmental issue. I'm on win7, working with ASP.NET out of Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Jeremy I'm also working on a Win7 box. I wish I knew how to fix the actual browser code. Something to aspire to eh? ;)

Comment: Same behavior on OS X 10.10, FFDE version 35.0a2 (2014-11-14).

Comment: Finally got this fixed on my win7x64 machine and mac os, see the answer provided for more info!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because there is a bug which is noted here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1091706 - Firefox team is very close to an update that fixes the problem, but until then you can use the following workaround to resolve (seen in update 2)

## Update 3:

Apparently, the bug fix mentioned in this answer is really a workaround - Firefox team is expected to patch their next update that will fix this problem automatically without the need to use the aforementioned work around - stay tuned!

## Update 2:

I was able to fix on Win7x64 by doing Help - TroubleShooting - refresh - Here are the steps:

1. Right click on top bar(where tabs are but not on a tab), select `Menu Bar`
2. Click on `Help` > `Troubleshooting Information`
3. Click on `Refresh Firefox Developer Edition...`

[image]

4. Confirm the refresh, then reload firefox.  *You should be good to go!*

> Note: You should do the refresh above instead of Uninstalling / Re-installing Firefox as that did not appear to work for me, I assume because the bug is stored in Roaming/Appdata or something similar, which does not get removed when uninstalling firefox. The refresh trick mentioned above worked great!

## Update

This just in! THere are reports of individuals stating their firefox is working properly.  According to the link mentioned above, you may be able to resolve the issue by resetting / resyncing your ff account.

This might explain why it works on my mac.  Going to see about windows tomorrow.

Comment: Oh god - I've been looking for this answer forever. Thank you! (Still a problem on 35.0a2)

Comment: Yeah my colleagues and I ran into this issue the other day and we were like wow how could they miss this?  The funny thing is, it works perfect on a mac.  Not sure about linux, but definitely is broken on windows!!!

Comment: Wow, maybe it's the version I downloaded? (35.0a2 (2014-11-15) It says there is a pending update but I haven't got it yet (might not want to, now!)

Comment: 2014-11-18 35.0a2 - This fix totally worked for me! Thanks @docodemore ! One more thing, if on Windows you can also access the "Tool Bar" by pressing the Alt key.

Comment: Hey guys, I had the same issue on Mac and it also affected the AngScope plugin (for angularJS). The workaround fixed it!

Comment: This fix worked temporarily for me. But after updating firefox recently it seems to be broken again. :(

Comment: @Noz - what version did you update to?  I dont think that they have released the lateset version that should ultimately fix this. until then, you may be to redo the workaround :(

Comment: Votes up all around! I was excited about FFDE but this bug made it nigh-unusable. Can't say I'm thrilled by how fragile and unintuitive the fix was though...

Comment: I have this issue with iceweasel 34.0 (firefox on Debian) as well. This workaround is not ideal as it deletes all user data (history, cookies, password, etc) - you could even more easily delete your $HOME/.mozilla directory with the same effect. I would be interested in WHAT exactly causes the bug. That it is a user profile specific setting, this is already clear...
Firefox/Iceweasel 36.0 fixes the issue for me in Debian unstable without all the hassle.